# API call from postman succeeds but fails from React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, token

I am calling an API on the backend from a React front-end. I am sending the token using Axios interceptors. I see the token on the network tab in the browser and also see a "provisional headers are show" message. The content type is Application/json.

However on the backend when the request is logged the content type is shown as null and the request body is also null. On the front end i see a generic cors error.

This same API works from postman.

Is there any reason the browser might be stripping the headers or any other reason the content type is changing to null?

Comment: Try adding CORS chrome extension to confirm if issue is because of CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS error is most probably your culprit. You need to add the API's endpoint domain (e.g. for an URL like `https://example.com/api/entity/1/related/2` you would add `https://example.com`) in the `content="..."` attribute of the `Content-Security-Policy` `<meta />` tag in the `<head>` of your HTML file, under the section the error tells you to (be it `connect-src`, `default-src`, etc.).

If you can provide the CORS error message you're getting (you can replace any specific domain names with something generic), then we can provide a more precise solution to your problem.